# FullCalendar long events are not shown on the top as allDay events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

```
event.start=obj.expected_start;
event.end=obj.expected_end;

format of expected_start: 2015-08-07 22:36:00
```

long events are rendering as normal events occupying full height of calendar.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/):

> **allDay**
>
> true or false. Optional.
>
> Whether an event occurs at a specific time-of-day. This property
>   affects whether an event's time is shown. Also, in the agenda views,
>   determines if it is displayed in the "all-day" section.
>
> If this value is not explicitly specified, allDayDefault will be used
>   if it is defined.
>
> If all else fails, FullCalendar will try to guess. If either the start
>   or end value has a "T" as part of the ISO8601 date string, allDay will
>   become false. Otherwise, it will be true.
>
> Don't include quotes around your true/false. This value is a boolean,
>   not a string!

The allDay slot is for events that don't have a time attribute:
i.e. `"2015-08-11" - "2015-08-14"` instead of `"2015-08-11T09:45:40" - "2015-08-11T11:45:40"`

It has nothing to do with how large the distance between start and end is.

Comment: It seems like it's not that they don't have a time attribute - they still could, they just don't show it.